# Load-time dynamic linking (import library) search order

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll

If I use a import library to implement [load-time dynamic linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686923.aspx) with a Windows system dll, which directory search order will be used?

Does it end up in the equivalent to `LoadLibrary("Iphlpapi.dll")`? Will it use a fully qualified path (i.e. `LoadLibrary("C:\\windows\\system32\\Iphlpapi.dll")`?

Some commonly used dlls (["known dlls"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/07/19/187752.aspx)) apparently receive special treatment, but how about other *system* dlls such as Iphlapi.dll?

Is it vulnerable to a [DLL preloading attack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2389418)?

Comment: The system DLLs (such as kernel32) are, as I understand matters, protected from preloading attacks.  If your question actually applies to other DLLs (for example, the Visual C runtime library) you might want to choose a different example.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I am talking about Windows provided dlls. But since I see that "Known DLLs" (of which kernel32.dll is one) receive special treatment, I have modified the question with a better example.

Comment: In the absence of a canonical answer supported by documentation, perhaps you could try it and see?  Move the DLL in question out of system32 and into the current directory, and see whether your application still runs.

Answer (score 0):

it should use the fully qualified path i.e ("C:\windows\system32\kernel.dll")...

Comment: kernel.dll does not exist. :-)

Comment: Caught out by this as well:  kernel32.dll?

Answer (score 0):

From the URL you mentionned, you are using the STATIC version of the Dynamic-link Library mechanism! This means that your application must be built using the corresponding LIB of the DLL (see explanation at this URL) and that the application will expect the DLL to be present when starting. Your application will NOT start should this DLL be missing (this is why this mechanism is called "Using Load-Time Dynamic Linking 
"). You cannot and don't have to invoke LoadLibrary. This will be automatically done by the Loader (since the dependency between your App and the DLL) has been put in the so-called Import Address Table (IAT) of your application.

Comment: Yes, this mechanism is a good candidate to DLL preloading attack!

Comment: To have a better control on this, you should better use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress APIs (compared to the previous mentioned mechanism, this is a true runtime Dynamic-Link Library - aka binding).

Comment: The mechanism described at the URL you mentioned (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686923.aspx) is general. In the case of Windows System DLLs, you have actually less control and flexibility in the search order.

Comment: Depending on the type of System DLLs you use and the 32/64 bit version of the OS, the System will use \system32 or other locations(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: For system DLLs you DON'T need to specify the full path. The Loader will take find its way to the correct Dll. For some System Dlls (Side-by-Side) the system will look for the correct version under \Windows\winsxs directory. At this location different versions of the same Dlls can coexist.